# What is going on in this map / string array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, dictionary

First, my code works fine. Nothing needs to be done, but as I copied some parts of the code from somewhere else, I dont fully understand whats happening here and hope for an explanation to learn something.

I use the play framework and send my controller class an AJAX POST with an ID and a score. I put those parameters into strings and save them in my DB.

```
Map<String, String[]> parameters = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded();
        String questionIDInput = parameters.get("questionID")[0];
        String voteScoreInput = parameters.get("score")[0];
```

The part I dont get is this: `.get("questionID")[0]; / .get("score")[0];`.
Why are the two zeros in there? Is the map some sort of a long String and I am using `"questionID / score"` as a key to find the values? The 0 really confuses me, enlighten me please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`parameters.get("questionID")` returns the value for the key "questionID". The value is a String array (`String[]`), so `parameters.get("questionID")[0]` gives you the first `String` of that array.

Note that this code assumes that the `"questionID"` key is present in the Map and that the value for that key is a non empty array. If any of those assumptions would turn out to be false, you'll get a `NullPointerException` or `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Ah so those are separate String-arrays ... and both have a different String at their first position, hence the 0. Learned something!

Answer (score 2):

The `Map` has a *key* and a *value* that corresponds to the key.

In your map, the key is of type `String`, whereas the value is of type `String[]` (an array of `String` object).

When you do `parameters.get("questionID")`, this will fetch the `String[]` array which corresponds to the key with value equal to `"questionId"`.

In order to get the first element of the returned array, `[0]` is used.

Comment: Thanks, helped me to understand.
Some sort of meta-question: You have edited my post and put "dictionary" back in there. I used the tag "map" which turned itself into "dictionary". So, why does the tag "map" turn into "dictionary" and why is "dictionary" an applicable tag for my question? (non-native english speaker here)

Comment: Probably the system automatically changes `map` to `dictionary`. Dunno exactly why.

Comment: Asked this on meta.stackoverflow ... lets see whats the explanation http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294564/why-does-the-tag-map-turn-into-dictionary-on-stackoverflow